Optimising large file import speed & memory usage
Im working on a project where I have to import large xml file such as 4BG with 40 millions of recods with person data that is then to be processed. Currently I have my code where at the start it would process around 5k/s although with the time the upload slows down & when at 300K + it would slow down to 20-30/s & eventually stopping.
The heap memory stays around 150-180 at all times & this is a requirement that I would keep it under 200.
What could be done here to optimise the memory usage & have it not clog up as much after some time & run more effectivley?
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FileImporter {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public FileImporter(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void insert(FileInformation fileInformation) throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO file_import (file_path, last_processed_row, status, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, fileInformation.getFilePath(), fileInformation.getLastProcessedRow(),
                    fileInformation.getStatus().toString(), fileInformation.getCreatedAt());
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while inserting file import data: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void update(FileInformation fileInformation) throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = """
                UPDATE file_import
                SET
                    file_path = ?,
                    last_processed_row = ?,
                    status = ?,
                    finished_at = ?,
                    started_at = ?
                WHERE id = ?
                """;
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, fileInformation.getFilePath(), fileInformation.getLastProcessedRow(),
                    fileInformation.getStatus().toString(), fileInformation.getFinishedAt(), fileInformation.getStartedAt(), fileInformation.getId());
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while updating file import data: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/file-imports")
@Slf4j
public class FileController {

    private final FileService fileService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FileImportStatusResponse> getFileImportStatus(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fileService.getFileImportStatus(id));
    }

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'IMPORTER')")
    public ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponse> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
         FileUploadResponse uploadResponse = fileService.uploadFile(file.getInputStream(), file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getSize());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(uploadResponse);

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class FileService {

    private final FileImportRepository fileImportRepository;

    private final FileProcessor fileProcessor;

    private final FileStorage fileStorage;

    private final FileImporter fileImporter;

    public FileUploadResponse uploadFile(InputStream inputStream, String originalFilename, long byteSize) {
        if (byteSize <= 0) {
            return new FileUploadResponse("Error occurred when uploading a file", originalFilename);
        }
        try {
            String uniqueFilename = fileStorage.save(inputStream, originalFilename, byteSize);

            FileInformation fileInformation = FileInformation.builder()
                    .filePath(uniqueFilename)
                    .lastProcessedRow(0L)
                    .status(FileStatus.PENDING)
                    .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();

            fileImporter.insert(fileInformation);

            FileUploadResponse response = new FileUploadResponse("File uploaded successfully. File name: " + uniqueFilename, uniqueFilename);
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Failed to upload the file", e);
            return new FileUploadResponse("Failed to upload the file.", originalFilename);
        }
    }

    @Async
    public Optional<Long> findFileToProcess() {
        return fileImportRepository.findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedAtAsc();

    }

    public void processFile(Long fileImportId) {
        FileInformation fileInformation = fileImportRepository.findById(fileImportId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Import file with id: " + fileImportId + " hasnt been found"));
        try {
            if (fileInformation.getStartedAt() == null) {
                fileInformation.setStartedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            }

            var processing = true;

            while (processing) {
                Long batchStart = fileInformation.getLastProcessedRow();
                FileProcessor.Result batchResult = fileProcessor.processFile(fileInformation, batchStart, 10);
                fileInformation.setLastProcessedRow(batchResult.lastProcessedRow());
                fileInformation.setStatus(FileStatus.IN_PROGRESS);
                processing = !batchResult.isFinished();
                fileImporter.update(fileInformation);
            }

            fileInformation.setFinishedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            fileInformation.setStatus(FileStatus.SUCCESS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error when processing file {}", fileImportId, e);
            fileInformation.setFinishedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            fileInformation.setStatus(FileStatus.FAILED);
        }
        fileImporter.update(fileInformation);
    }

    public FileImportStatusResponse getFileImportStatus(Long id) {
        Optional<FileInformation> fileImportOptional = fileImportRepository.findById(id);
        return fileImportOptional.map(this::buildStatusResponse)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("File import status not found!"));
    }

    private FileImportStatusResponse buildStatusResponse(FileInformation fileInformation) {
        return new FileImportStatusResponse(
                fileInformation.getStatus(),
                fileInformation.getCreatedAt(),
                fileInformation.getStartedAt(),
                fileInformation.getLastProcessedRow());
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class FileProcessor {

    public record Result(long lastProcessedRow, boolean isFinished) {
    }

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    private final PersonValidator personValidator;

    private final Map<String, PersonCreationStrategy> creationStrategyMap;

    private final ComposedCsvFileRowToCreateCommandStrategy csvFileRowToCreateCommandStrategy;

    private final FileStorage fileStorage;

    @Transactional
    public Result processFile(FileInformation fileInformation, long batchStart, long batchSize) throws IOException {
        AtomicInteger processedLines = new AtomicInteger();


        try (BufferedReader reader = fileStorage.load(fileInformation.getFilePath())) {
            var lines = reader.lines();
            Stream<String> batchLines = lines.skip(1).skip(batchStart).limit(batchSize);
            List<Person> entities = batchLines.map(line -> {
                Person person = processFileLine(line);
                personValidator.validate(person);
                processedLines.getAndIncrement();
                return person;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            personValidator.validatePersonsForBatchSave(entities);
            personRepository.saveAllAndFlush(entities);
        }

        boolean isFinished = processedLines.get() < batchSize;
        return new Result(batchStart + processedLines.get(), isFinished);
    }

    private Person processFileLine(String line) {
        String[] data = line.split(",");
        String type = data[0];
        String key = type.toLowerCase() + "CreationStrategy";
        PersonCreationStrategy strategy = creationStrategyMap.get(key);
        Person person;

        if (strategy != null) {
            person = createAndAddToDatabase(strategy, data);
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Unknown type: " + type);
        }
        return person;
    }

    private Person createAndAddToDatabase(PersonCreationStrategy strategy, String[] data) {
        CreatePersonCommand command = mapDataToCommand(data);
        return strategy.create(command);
    }

    private CreatePersonCommand mapDataToCommand(String[] data) {
        return csvFileRowToCreateCommandStrategy.toCommand(data);
    }
}

I have attempted to use garbage collector on demand but it seems that the heap usage is much lower although it still slows down after some time.
